# CSS Grid unexpected distribution in interactive repro

Tags: css-grid

I would think this is a browser bug, but the behavior is identical in Chrome and Firefox current versions tested (on Windows).

Why does long, wrapped text cause the column distribution to be adjusted?  Even after wrapping, it continues to adjust as the wrapped text gets longer.  You can see it with the fixed selections or with the interactively sizeable textarea (the textarea behavior is slightly more expected, just there for ease of the demonstration - I don't really care much about the textarea working or not.)

https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-sea-1pwcl

[image: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-sea-1pwcl]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a tip in the discussion of [this filed bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1148890) the answer is

> ...your tracks are intrinsically sized, so in order to calculate the grid area, we need the intrinsic contributions of the grid items. So when calculating these, the max-width percentage is cyclic!
> ...Basically, what you want is to avoid taking the intrinsic contribution
> of the textarea when sizing tracks. My suggestion is to take advantage
> of
>
> > For the min size properties, as well as for margins and paddings (and gutters), a cyclic percentage is resolved against zero for
> > determining intrinsic size contributions.
>
> and style the grid item that contains the textarea with:
>
> ```
> width: 0; /* Sets intrinsic width to 0 */
> min-width: 100%; /* Has no effect during intrinsic sizing, overrides the declaration above when laying out for real */
> ```